# Google Chrome in Mac OS X - How to open link in Chrome when it's not the default browser?

Tags: macos, mac, google-chrome, browser, services

In Google Chrome in Mac OS X, is it possible to keep Safari as default browser but have an easy way to open a chosen link in Chrome other than dropping the link on the Chrome icon? Maybe something like 'Open in Chrome' from Services menu when right-clicking a link?

Comment: Related discussion: [OS X Automator action for url in Safari](http://superuser.com/a/190882/163596) and [Apple SE: In a Service, how to get a URL from rich text?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/41277/34902)

Comment: ...or perhaps a plist file modification?

Comment: Here's my use case, for what it's worth: Safari is my default browser, and I like it that way. But I want to open Google URLs (Google Docs, YouTube, etc.) in Chrome by default, e.g., when I click on a link in Mail. Is there a system-level way to set the default browser for a sub-set of domains?

Answer (score 2):

This is a Duct Tape way of doing it. It isn't fancy or automated in the sense of how I understand you want to do it, however in the interim before someone gives you an actual answer, you can do this:

1. Click and Drag the Link to the Dock
2. Drop the Link onto the Chrome Icon
3. URL opens in Chrome.

If you were to click it instead, it would open in default browser.

That being said, there must be a way, as when you think about it, clicking a link in Chrome or Firefox opens that link in Chrome or Firefox, not Safari.

Some of the answers out there talked about 3rd party apps that can capture the HTTP or HTTPS of the click, but it wasn't definitive from the comments if they actually worked.

Answer (score 1):

There are extensions that should provide this functionality. Search for *"Open with Chrome for Safari"*.

[This answer over on Ask Different which mentions the 'Open in Chrome' service](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/32909/143571) may help you as well.